# A mac app for screen annotation?

Tags: osx, macos

I want to draw on all over the screen and not just on a single screen or app. Is there any mac app that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Presentify**. It lets you annotate your screen and also highlight your cursor/mouse. You can draw over anything, be it images, pdf, browser, videos, and the list goes on. The app is available on the Mac App Store.

[image]

Website: https://presentify.compzets.com/
Mac App Store: https://apps.apple.com/app/presentify/id1507246666
Demo: https://youtu.be/CTR1iAbGhjg (this video is of an older version, the newer version has a lot more features)

I hope you find it useful.

*Disclosure: I am the developer of the app.*

Comment: Nice app. I just bought it.